# Google Map lng + lat to hidden field not working

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am trying to get Marker data into hidden fields on my form.  I'm not sure why this isn't working, it must be something in my js syntax:

```
var initialLocation;
var siberia = new google.maps.LatLng(60, 105);
var newyork = new google.maps.LatLng(40.69847032728747, -73.9514422416687);
var browserSupportFlag =  new Boolean();




function initialize() {
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 6,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    myListener = google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    placeMarker(event.latLng), google.maps.event.removeListener(myListener);

  });





  // Try W3C Geolocation (Preferred)
  if(navigator.geolocation) {
    browserSupportFlag = true;
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      initialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
      map.setCenter(initialLocation);
    }, function() {
      handleNoGeolocation(browserSupportFlag);
    });
  // Try Google Gears Geolocation
  } else if (google.gears) {
    browserSupportFlag = true;
    var geo = google.gears.factory.create('beta.geolocation');
    geo.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      initialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.latitude,position.longitude);
      map.setCenter(initialLocation);
    }, function() {
      handleNoGeoLocation(browserSupportFlag);
    });
  // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
  } else {
    browserSupportFlag = false;
    handleNoGeolocation(browserSupportFlag);
  }

  function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) {
    if (errorFlag == true) {
      alert("Geolocation service failed.");
      initialLocation = newyork;
    } else {
      alert("Your browser doesn't support geolocation. We've placed you in Siberia.");
      initialLocation = siberia;
    }
  }
  function placeMarker(location) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: location, 
      map: map,
      draggable: true
  });

  map.setCenter(location);


}
}

var lat = latlng.lat();
  var lng = latlng.lng();
document.getElementById("t1").value=lat;
document.getElementById("t2").value=lng;
```

---

```
 <input type="hidden" name="lat" id="t1">
    <input type="hidden" name="long" id="t2">
```

Answer (score 1):

[JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) is a wonderful tool.

> Problem at line 17 character 30: Missing semicolon.
>
> ```
> placeMarker(event.latLng), google.maps.event.removeListener(myListener);
> ```
>
> Problem at line 17 character 30: Expected an identifier and instead saw ','.
>
> ```
> placeMarker(event.latLng), google.maps.event.removeListener(myListener);
> ```

Change that comma to a semicolon, run it through JSLint again and keep going until there are no more errors.

Comment: That is a really cool tool - adding to bookmarks.  Unfortunately, I cleaned up all of the code and it's still not working.

Answer (score 1):

take a look:  [on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q8s7r/2/)

---

var lat = initialLocation.lat(), lng = initialLocation.lng();

Comment: Hmm...  Can't get that to work.  Where were you thinking that goes?

Comment: I got your code to work, but this is for the initial position from the Geo locater.  I need to get the lng, lat from the markers.