# Google Map - issue with map drag not releasing

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a google map that is not releasing from being dragged when the mouse click is released.  When I click the mouse, drag the map and release the click, the map still keeps dragging with the mouse.  This causes some strange positioning stuff while users are trying to place markers.  Here is my code:

```
    var initialLocation;
    var siberia = new google.maps.LatLng(44.9111410149792, -93.0537195);
    var newyork = new google.maps.LatLng(40.69847032728747, -73.9514422416687);
    var browserSupportFlag =  new Boolean();



    function initialize() {
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 6,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

        myListener = google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
            placeMarker(event.latLng);
            google.maps.event.removeListener(myListener);
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'drag', function(event) {
            placeMarker(event.latLng);
            google.maps.event.removeListener(myListener);
        });

        // Try W3C Geolocation (Preferred)
        if(navigator.geolocation) {
            browserSupportFlag = true;
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                initialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
                map.setCenter(initialLocation);
            }, function() {
                handleNoGeolocation(browserSupportFlag);
            });
            // Try Google Gears Geolocation
        } else if (google.gears) {
            browserSupportFlag = true;
            var geo = google.gears.factory.create('beta.geolocation');
            geo.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                initialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.latitude,position.longitude);
                map.setCenter(initialLocation);
            }, function() {
                handleNoGeoLocation(browserSupportFlag);
            });
            // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
        } else {
            browserSupportFlag = false;
            handleNoGeolocation(browserSupportFlag);
        }

        function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) {
            if (errorFlag === true) {
                alert("Geolocation service failed.");
                initialLocation = newyork;
            } else {
                alert("Your browser doesn't support geolocation. We've placed you in beautiful Minneapolis.");
                initialLocation = siberia;
            }
                map.setCenter(initialLocation);

        }

        function placeMarker(location) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: location,
                map: map,
                draggable: true
            });
            map.setCenter(location);
            var markerPosition = marker.getPosition();
            populateInputs(markerPosition);
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "drag", function (mEvent) {
                populateInputs(mEvent.latLng);
            });
        }
        function populateInputs(pos) {
            document.getElementById("t1").value=pos.lat()
            document.getElementById("t2").value=pos.lng();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is the same code I posted in your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4533303/google-maps-v3-populate-text-field-with-marker-data/4533962#4533962), and it was working just fine..anyway I've pasted the above code in [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/owidi3) and it's still working!  maybe you have other functions or markup on the page that is causing the problem

Comment: What I'm talking about is how the map drags along with a mouse click.  Once the mouse click is released, the map drag should release as well.  With the code I posted map drag is not released with a mouse release.  Here's an example of the map drag behaving as it should:

http://jsbin.com/aqoso4

Answer (score 2):

Delete this part of the script. it worked for me:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'drag', function(event) {
    placeMarker(event.latLng);
    google.maps.event.removeListener(myListener);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear whether it is the whole map or the marker you are talking about when you say "is being dragged with the mouse".
As far as I can tell your solution is for markers only.

The code below shows how you can set the draggable property, which can be true or false. true means draggable false means not.

```
function placeMarker(location) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: location,
                map: map,
                draggable: true
            });
```