# Google Map V3 - Getting geoPostition data into hidden field

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a Google map that uses W3C geoLocation to get a persons location.  I would like to know how to get the lat and lng of their initial position into a hidden field.

```
        // Try W3C Geolocation (Preferred)
        if(navigator.geolocation) {
            browserSupportFlag = true;
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                initialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
                map.setCenter(initialLocation);
            }, function() {
                handleNoGeolocation(browserSupportFlag);
            });
            // Try Google Gears Geolocation
        } else if (google.gears) {
            browserSupportFlag = true;
            var geo = google.gears.factory.create('beta.geolocation');
            geo.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                initialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.latitude,position.longitude);
                map.setCenter(initialLocation);
            }, function() {
                handleNoGeoLocation(browserSupportFlag);
            });
            // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
        } else {
            browserSupportFlag = false;
            handleNoGeolocation(browserSupportFlag);
        }

        function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) {
            if (errorFlag === true) {
                alert("Geolocation service failed.");
                initialLocation = newyork;
            } else {
                alert("Your browser doesn't support geolocation. We've placed you in beautiful Minneapolis.");
                initialLocation = siberia;
            }
                map.setCenter(initialLocation);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like the approach I used in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4533303/google-maps-v3-populate-text-field-with-marker-data/4533962#4533962):
In the `getCurrentPosition` method:

```
populateInputs(initialLocation);
```

Where function looks like:

```
function populateInputs(pos) {
    document.getElementById("t1").value=pos.lat()
    document.getElementById("t2").value=pos.lng();
}
```

Where t1 and t2 are your hidden fields

Answer (score 0):

Just before (the two places) you get initialLocation, you're given the lat and longitude (as: position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude or position.latitude,position.longitude).
just call a function to set a hidden field at that point (passing in the lat and long).  Something like:

```
var setHiddenField = function(lat, long) {
    document.forms[0].hiddenLatField.value = lat;
    document.forms[0].hiddenLongField.value = long;
}
```

...I'm assuming only 1 form on your page, but you should be easily able to tweak this.